# How to say "to think of something intelligent to say"

Tags: grammaire, traduction, choix-de-mot

How would you translate this sentence into French:

> I wanted to think of something intelligent to say to her.

I came up with this but I don't know if it's correct:

> Je voulais trouver quelque chose d’intelligent à lui dire.

Comment: Hmm... je cherche quelque chose d'intelligent à te répondre ;-)

Comment: @aCOSwt Haha, donc on doit employer le verbe "chercher". Et le reste de la phrase est correct ?

Comment: Ha... C'est si tu veux hein. C'est toi l'auteur => Il n'y a pas de *on doit*. C'est toi qui commandes! Je disais cela en tant qu'autre solution possible. Ton *Je voulais trouver* passe aussi très bien. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Je voulais trouver quelque chose d’intelligent à lui dire.

Et tout à fait correct

On peut également dire

> Je cherchais quelque chose d'intelligent à lui dire

Ou

> Je cherchais une réponse intelligente à lui dire

Sinon un peu plus complexe

> Je cherchais une réponse **pertinente** à lui dire

https://www.wordreference.com/fren/pertinent

Comment: *Je cherchais* plutôt que *je cherche*. *I wanted* peut aussi se traduire par *j'ai voulu*.

Comment: merci, je rectifie